# Java - Editable text area

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, textarea

i'm wondering if there is an other way than use a jTextArea (or jTextField), to make some editable text area in Java?

I must be able to drag & drop this area, this is mostly the reason why i can't use a jTextArea, when i click on it, he gains the focus (the little cursor blinks) so i can't detect a mousePressed event for example.

Thank for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Strongly appears to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976972/swing-jtextfield-dnd-replace-the-existing-text-with-the-import-test

Answer (score 0):

When you say drag and drop the area, do you mean the whole component or drag and drop into the component?

If you mean the component itself you're going to have to get a bit creative. If it's the latter I don't have much experience with that.

One possible work around might be that instead of clicking a mouse button to start dragging the component, you press a key. For arguments sake let's say alt. You move the mouse to where you want to drag it to, then release the alt.

Not that it actually helps you with your problem mind you, but there is also a JEditorPane. It would still gain focus when you click inside it though.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but what i'm trying to do is a kind of add-on for an existing software (student project) and the drag & drop is done with the mouse, i can't help it...
About JEditorPane, it seems be usefull for displaying some web content in a graphic component but I don't see how it could used in my case.
Ty anyway =)

Comment: It suddenly hit me just now. What if you clicked on the borders of your text components? Perhaps make them larger to make it easier to click on them.

Comment: Yes that's quite the trick i used to solve my problem, i set an other object a bit larger behind the textfield, then when i click on the border, i can use drag events on this object. Thx anyway :)